# javascript undefined error - getting a value from a form

Tags: javascript, forms, jsp, undefined

I'm a beginner! I started to study javascript, but there is an error what I can't find a way to solve it.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
>       at correct (homework.jsp:50)
>       at HTMLInputElement.onclick (homework.jsp:63)

It happens when I put the 'done' button. I wanted to get a value from a form. But the value is always 'undefined' and I couldn't change it to Number or String. Maybe I failed from getting the value. Could you kindly help me?

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<h2>Homework</h2>
<form name="gugu">
<script type="text/javascript">
    //How many questions?
    var size=eval(window.prompt("How many questions?"));
    var a=new Array(size);
    var b=new Array(size);
    var ans=new Array(size);
    var rst=new Array(size);
    var count=0;

    //Start
    gugugu();
    function gugugu() {
        document.write("<table border='1'>");
        for (var i=0; i<size+1; i++) {
            if(i<size) {
                document.write("<tr>");
                document.write("<td>");
                    a[i]=parseInt(Math.random()*9)+1;
                    b[i]=parseInt(Math.random()*9)+1;
                    rst[i]=a[i]*b[i];
                    document.write(a[i]+"*"+b[i]+"=");
                document.write("</td>");
                document.write("<td>");
                    //I can't get the value!
                    var str="<input type='text' name='"+i+"'>";
                    document.write(str);
                document.write("</td>");
                document.write("</tr>");
            } else {
                document.write("<tr>");
                document.write("<td colspan='2' align='center'>");
                    document.write("<input type='button' value='done' onclick='correct()'>");
                    document.write("<input type='button' value='reset' onclick='reset()'>");
                document.write("</td>");
                document.write("</tr>");
            }
        }
        document.write("</table>");
        document.write("count : ");
        document.write("<input type='text' value='' name='count' readonly>");
        document.write("<br>");
        document.write("note : ");
        document.write("<input type='text' value='' name='note' readonly>");
    }
    function correct() {
        for (var i=0; i<size;i++) {
            //Here I tried putting values into an Array, but 'undefined' happens!
            ans[i]=String(document.gugu.i.value);
            document.write(typeof(ans[i])+","+rst[i]+"<br>");
            if(ans[i]==rst[i]) {
                count=count+1;
            }
        }
        document.gugu.count.value=eval(count);
        document.gugu.note.value=eval(count*10);
    }
    function reset() {
        clear();
        gugugu();
    }
</script>
</form>
```

Comment: are you sure `gugu` is in your `document`?

Comment: @HagaiWild Unfortunately I think so... You mean that the form has been at a wrong line written, right? I'll try to modify on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"gugu" its the form name, document.gugu is undefined, because its not a global variable, to get the form: document.getElementsByName("gugu");

```
ans[i]=String(document.gugu.i.value);
```

then after getting the form (in an HTMLElement[] type), you are trying to get a row?, you cant do FORM.i,  "i" has no context here, access it from the array ans[], this way you can get the value from the input by their name (numbers you set as name):

```
ans[i] = String(document.getElementsByName("" + i)[0].values[i]);
```

So with a few changes here and there this works:

```
<h2>Homework</h2>
<form name="gugu">
<script type="text/javascript">
    //How many questions?
    var size = eval(window.prompt("How many questions?"));
    var a = new Array(size);
    var b = new Array(size);
    var ans = new Array(size);
    var rst = new Array(size);
    var count = 0;

    //Start
    gugugu();
    function gugugu() {
        document.write("<table border='1'>");
        for (var i = 0; i < size + 1; i++) {
            if (i < size) {
                document.write("<tr>");
                document.write("<td>");
                a[i] = parseInt(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
                b[i] = parseInt(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
                rst[i] = a[i] * b[i];
                document.write(a[i] + "*" + b[i] + "=");
                document.write("</td>");
                document.write("<td>");
                var str = "<input type='text' name='in" + i + "'>";
                document.write(str);
                document.write("</td>");
                document.write("</tr>");
            } else {
                document.write("<tr>");
                document.write("<td colspan='2' align='center'>");
                document.write("<input type='button' value='done' onclick='correct()'>");
                document.write("<input type='button' value='reset' onclick='reset()'>");
                document.write("</td>");
                document.write("</tr>");
            }
        }
        document.write("</table>");
        document.write("count : ");
        document.write("<input type='text' value='' name='count' readonly>");
        document.write("<br>");
        document.write("note : ");
        document.write("<input type='text' value='' name='note' readonly>");
    }
    function correct() {
        console.log("correct");
        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            ans[i] = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("in" + i)[0].value);
            console.log(ans[i]);
            console.log(rst[i]);
            if (ans[i] === rst[i]) {
                count = count + 1;
            }
        }
        console.log(count);

        document.getElementsByName("count")[0].value = count;
        document.getElementsByName("note")[0].value = (count * 10);
    }
    function reset() {
        clear();
        gugugu();
    }
</script>
</form>
```

Comment: You are right! I solved it with your help. I changed that line as this. ans[i] = document.gugu.elements[i].value; and then it works! Finally I can sleep! Thank you so much <3

Comment: you are welcome, dont forget to come often and help others! :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't access html elements like this `document.something`. Check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp) to see the different ways to access html elements using JavaScript.

Comment: Oh, I didn't learn them yet. I didn't know that website has those nice examples I can try. It will be very helpful. Thank you!